# Apache disable localhost redirection

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts, laragon

i got a problem with apache conf with Laragon.

so the case is :

i got 2 subdomain 
subdom1.mysite.com (DNS Record to IP 1.2.3.4)
subdom2.mysite.com (DNS Record to IP 1.2.3.4)
IP 1.2.3.4 is my VPS

everything went well, but i got a problem.
when i access 'localhost' from my VPS, it keeps redirecting to subdom1.mysite.com
and localhost/phpMyAdmin also redirected to subdom1.mysite.com/phpMyAdmin

here's my httpd.conf

```
Define APACHE_LOG_DIR "C:/mydir/logs"
Define APACHE_ROOT_WEB_DIR "C:/mydir/wwwroot"

ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/mydir/wwwroot"

<Directory "C:/mydir/wwwroot">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdom1.mysite.com
    ServerAlias subdom1.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot  ${APACHE_ROOT_WEB_DIR}\subdom1.mysite.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdom1.mysite.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdom1.mysite.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdom2.mysite.com
    ServerAlias subdom2.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_ROOT_WEB_DIR}\subdom2.mysite.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdom2.mysite.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdom2.mysite.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my localhost keeps redirecting to first vHost. I've googled lot's of combination of directory, serverName etc. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your `VirtualHost`s are binding to all available interfaces. Because of [how apache determines to which VHost should route](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html#hostmatching) a request, it's ending up in the first one defined.

You can either:

- Bind your subdomains to the external ip only.
- Create a `VirtualHost` for the main server using the loopback ip.
- Create a `VirtualHost` with the [`_default_`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#default) address.